# How to set up a keyboard shortcut for "I'm feeling lucky" in Google?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-search

I want to avoid using my mouse to click the button "I'm feeling lucky", like how you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get your search results. How to set up a shortcut key for this button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, then press enter.

X = <kbd>Tab</kbd> * 2 + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: wouldn't that be XX ? :)

Comment: Can we settle on X = tab(2) ? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#IfWinActive, Google
x::{Tab 2}{Return}
#IfWinActive
```

There's your X :)
(John T's answer in AHK form)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a specialised search depending on which browser you use and call that via shortcut or special command.

Answer (score 0):

Type it in your browser location bar, and you have set it to use google.